# Windbg: Can't get next object after a Free object

Tags: debugging, windbg

I know that fragmentation typically occurs when an object collected by
garbage collection is marked as a "free" block, but the object
occupying the next address space is pinned. I can get a list of Free
objects, but cannot seem to find out what is pinned next to it.

I dump the object, find its size, and then add its size to the
original object address to get the next object, like this:

0:000> !do 0a2467c8
Free Object
Size 438312(0x6b028) bytes

0:000> !do 0a2467c8+438312
 Invalid object

I can never get the next, pinned object to show up. Its always
invalid. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Figured it out. When you step to the next object, the value must be in HEX, not in decimal.

Comment: or `!do 0a2467c8+0n438312` where `0n` is the prefix for decimal values

Answer (score 1):

WinDbg does not always work out as planned.
Check out Mark Russinovich’s latest utility.

ProcDump v1.0, a 1.0 worth every ounce of mention.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx

ProcDump is a command-line utility whose primary purpose is monitoring an application for CPU spikes and generating crash dumps during a spike that an administrator or developer can use to determine the cause of the spike. ProcDump also includes hung window monitoring (using the same definition of a window hang that Windows and Task Manager use) and unhandled exception monitoring. It also can serve as a general process dump utility that you can embed in other scripts.